# Possible to use Siri to trigger custom actions?

Tags: macos, mac, siri

These days, Macs have Siri.

Siri even works offline for tasks like dictation.

When Siri interprets audio into written words, can I somehow capture those written words, and trigger a self-defined action if a certain pattern is detected?

For example, if I say "Hey Siri, run my backup script", could a shell script located in my home folder then be executed?

(Bonus question: If Siri cannot do this, is there some other free technology that can?)

Answer (score 2):

That’s one interesting idea. It seems to be possible by registering custom vocabulary in your app. Since there is `SiriKit` it should be possible. Besides people from `Homebridge` achieved the same you want with garage doors and so on.
https://github.com/nfarina/homebridge/blob/master/README.md

Things like custom vocabulary can be found here:
https://developer.apple.com/documentation/sirikit/registering_custom_vocabulary_with_sirikit

So if I understand the docs correctly you can specify

`IntentPhrases` that allow you to react for a word `shell` for exemple

But I love the idea. First thing I will connect will be ‘fastlane’ and I will shout ‘deploy!’

Answer (score 1):

While it seems possible through Siri, using the built in dictation commands seem easier to run a script.

You can see how here:
https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/LanguagesUtilities/Conceptual/MacAutomationScriptingGuide/UseDictationtoRunScripts.html